# Bought Chametz on Pesach

Tags: passover

If I accidentally walk into a store on Pesach and buy a product which contains Chametz- what do I do?

Am I obligated to burn it etc?

Comment: Why would you not be obligated to burn it etc?

Comment: If you bought it on actual Moed (breaking another halacha), then we might have a machloket.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot meaning?

Comment: @ephraim and which day of Pesach is not an actual moed?

Comment: Sorry-- I meant to exclude Chol HaMoed. What term is correct for days 1 and 7?

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot Probably "Yom Tov" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rambam (Chametz U'Matzah 1:3) writes: "[A violator] is not lashed for [transgressing the prohibitions] not to have [chametz] seen [in his possession] and not to have [chametz] found [in his possession] **unless he purchased chametz on Pesach** or [caused flour] to become leavened, and thus committed a deed.

So it is forbidden. However, since it was an accident, there is no punishment.

The Shulchan Aruch O.C. 446; with Mishnah Berurah,(see also 445 for erev Pesach for background )explains that the obligation is to burn it right away on Chol HaMoed. However, one may also dispose of it in the river. Therefore, it would seem that nowadays, since it usually takes a while to start a suitable fire in a suitable location, and people usually have toilets immediately available; the preferred way to rid oneself of Chametz would be to flush it since there is much less time waiting around while it is in your possession.

However, the real question is if the "product" you accidentally bought is obligated in such destruction. The exact law would vary depending on how much Chametz is in it (0.90 oz. of real chametz should require a brachah as well), If it is discernable, edible (for a dog) etc. Instead of simply destroying it, one should ask their LOR to look up the product and clearly define it, before issuing a ruling.

Comment: I don't see such a statement in Shulchan Arukh OC 445. Note the Halakhot of how to do Biur may differ Kodem and Achar Shaat Issuro, and I'm not sure it's obvious that the time spent building a fire [to be machmir for rabbenu tam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15602/759) is a problem since you are working on destroying it, like walking slowly out of the mikdash while tamei.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited based on part of your comment. You raise an interesting issue re: time spent building a fire.

Comment: Chabad is now providing a free opportunity to sell Chametz with no charge before Pesach. PS. halachic authorities authorizated this. So it’s legal. Link below: https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/sell_chometz_cdo/sc/top_ad

Comment: @TurkHill No, please don't use their form! It's certainly legal, but they sell your dishes to a non-Jew too so you'd have to go dip them all in a Mikva again. What a pain! (There's a small minority opinion in Lubavitch that you don't need to dunk them again, so if you follow all Lubavitch customs you could potentially use that link. Otherwise, stay far away!)

Comment: Ty for the head's up.